# Events not firing inside mapboxgl popup

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, mapbox

I'm attempting to do something custom with clusters, where when you click down on a cluster that cannot be expanded further (eg. two objects with the same or very similar location data), a list of what is contained in that cluster should appear, which you can then interact with. I am able to retrieve the objects, create the list and place it on the correct spot on the map, but I am unable to bind any events to those list entries. I have created similar functionality in other parts of the map application, and these seem to be working as expected. Those were not created using the Popup library, so I could try reusing that technique, but the ease of placing popups makes me want to at least try to get those working with events.

I've tried using `addEventListener` with the `click`, `mouseup` and `mouseenter` events, but nothing is triggering.

How can I use eventListeners in mapbox popups? Is the HTML passed to the popup being sanitized somehow?

I am currently using mapboxgl 1.2.0.

How the popup is generated:

```
new mapboxgl.Popup({offset:25}).setHTML(generateListPopup(myEntries).outerHTML)
                            .setLngLat(coords[0])
                            .addTo($scope.map);
```

How the content is generated:

```
function generateListPopup(entries){
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        container.maxHeight = "240px";
        container.overflowY = "auto";
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.style.listStyle = "none";
        ul.style.padding = "0";
        container.style.background = "blue"; // does set the color to blue
        container.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () { // does not trigger
            console.log("by golly"); // does not show
        });
        angular.forEach(entries, function (e) {
            var li = document.createElement('li');
            var entry = document.createElement('p');
            var f = document.createElement('button');
            entry.innerHTML = e.name;
            entry.style.cursor = "pointer";
            f.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
                console.log("hello"); // nope
            });
            li.appendChild(f);
            li.appendChild(entry);
            ul.appendChild(li);
        });
        container.appendChild(ul);
        return container;
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just typed out this whole question before figuring it out, so might as well post it in case anyone ever has the same issue:

use `setDOMContent` on the returned container instead of `setHTML` on the returned container's `outerHTML`. I'm guessing the bound events are lost when the elements are serialized using `outerHTML`.